# simplifying this expression of square roots

Tags: polynomials

Is there anyway to further simplify this expression without actually squaring each of the large squared terms? The extra term $(a-c)$ within the second square is throwing me off.

$$[(c-a)^2+d^2+b^2]^2-[(a-c)(c-a)+d^2-b^2]^2-4d^2b^2$$

Comment: Hint:  $(a-c)(c-a)=-(c-a)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use the factorisation $ X^2-Y^2=(X-Y)(X+Y) $.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Since $(a-c)=-(c-a)$ we have:

$$
[(c-a)^2+d^2+b^2]^2-[d^2-b^2-(c-a)^2]^2-4d^2b^2=
$$

$$
=(d^2+b^2)^2+(c-a)^4+2(d^2+b^2)(c-a)^2-(d^2-b^2)^2-(c-a)^4+2(d^2-b^2)(c-a)^2-4d^2b^2
$$
Now note that $(d^2+b^2)^2-(d^2-b^2)^2=4d^2b^2$, eliminate the two opposite $(c-a)^4$ and factorize $(c-a)^2$ in the other terms..... and you have a simple result.